# Deleting all rows from Cassandra cql table

Tags: cassandra, cql

Is there a command to all the rows present in a cql table in cassandra like the one in sql?

```
delete from TABLE
```

Going by the documentation, I don't find any way to perform delete operation without a where condition.

```
DELETE col1 FROM SomeTable WHERE userID = 'some_key_value';
```

Answer (score 190, accepted):

To remove all rows from a CQL Table, you can use the [TRUNCATE](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/truncate_r.html) command:

```
TRUNCATE keyspace_name.table_name;
```

Or if you are already using the keyspace that contains your target table:

```
TRUNCATE table_name;
```

Important to note, but by default Cassandra creates a snapshot of the table just prior to TRUNCATE.  Be sure to clean up old snapshots, or set `auto_snapshot: false` in your cassandra.yaml.

Comment: How to delete all rows without creating snapshot and editing cassandra config ?

Comment: @Vinigas It's a little difficult with those restrictions, so deleting the SSTable files from the keyspace/table directory might be your only option.  The safer path would probably be to `TRUNCATE` and then run a `nodetool clearsnapshot` afterward.

Comment: I guess you could just describe table (copy the creation command), then drop table and create table... does it make sense?